# primary stress of "Flying Squad" and "Flying Scotsman"

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

Do you know why the primary stress falls on the "Scotsman" of "Flying Scotsman" but on the first component of "Flying Squad" according to the dictionary?

Here are the definitions of the two expressions:

> Flying Squad: ​a group of police officers in the UK who are ready to travel very quickly to the scene of a serious crime
>
> Flying Scotsman: a British steam railway engine, built in 1923, which was the fastest of its kind for many years.

Comment: I don't detect any difference in stress. I would stress both evenly (and the same with flying doctor and flying officer)

Comment: The difference is demonstrated here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flying-squad?q=flying+squad

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/the-flying-scotsman?q=flying+scotsman

Comment: Thanks, but my introspection stands. I don't detect any difference in stress pattern in a normal speech.

Comment: Do you hear the difference in the two links given above?

Comment: Not really.  Both have an Up-Down intonation pattern, with a rise on the adjective and a fall on the noun. Both words seem to receive roughly equal stress. I can imagine that in a context like "We don't need the drugs squad 'ere; we need *flying* squad. Get Jack Regan on the blower!"  Then there might be contrastive stress.  (reference *The Sweeny*, a cop show about two flying squad officers)

Comment: The "primary" stress differs as ***'fly**-ing squad* and *flying **'scots**-man*.

Answer (score 1):

It's the *Flying* Squad as distinct from the Drugs Squad, Vice Squad or whatever.

The loco was called Scotsman because it pulled the express train between London and Edinburgh; *flying* is just an attribute.

Comment: While "drugs squad" and "vice squad" are easily understandable, in what sense is "flying" distinct from "drugs" and "vice"?

Comment: I meant that it distinguishes the 'rapid response' team from other specialist teams in the police service.

Comment: It sounds like "flying" as in "flying squad" is also an attribute, meaning the police act quickly. If so, there seems to be little difference from the "flying" in "Flying Scotsman."

Comment: Yes, but it identifies that particular squad among others. There wasn't a 'running Scotsman' or 'creeping Scotsman' that the Flying Scotsman had to be distinguished from!

Comment: What if a train service is offered and called "running Scotsman"? Would that change the status of "Flying" as in "Flying Scotsman"?

Comment: That's such an unlikely hypothesis, and the Flying Scotsman is so famous, that it's difficult to say!